# How to get selected document on viewPanel of xPage for external source data?

Tags: javascript, xpages

Here is my simple view that users JDBCQUERY as a source data. And it shows each row with a checkbox so you can select:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" showColumnHeader="false">
        <xp:this.data>
            <xe:jdbcQuery var="view1" scope="request">
                <xe:this.sqlQuery><![CDATA[#{javascript:"SELECT COLUMN1 FROM MYTABLE"}]]></xe:this.sqlQuery>
                <xe:this.connectionName><![CDATA[#{javascript:"DB2"}]]></xe:this.connectionName>
            </xe:jdbcQuery>
        </xp:this.data>

        <xp:viewColumn columnName="COLUMN1" id="viewColumn1" showCheckbox="true">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader1" rendered="false"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
    </xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

Now to get selected documents I use method/button:

```
var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");
var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
for(i=0;i < docIDArray.length; i++){
    print(docIDArray[i]);
}
```

Since it's not NotesView/NotesDocument data it returns just row number of selected row (not document UNID)... getSelectedIds() returns selected rows 1 and 3.

Now how do I get column value of selected row (value2 and value4)?
Is it something like that: getRow(3).getColumValues()... ?

```
     COLUMN1
[ ]  value1
[x]  value2
[ ]  value3
[x]  value4
[ ]  value5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `<xp:viewPanel>` is not appropriate for the task.
I would change it for a `<xp:dataTable>`, although, at that point you need to re-implement the selection mechanism. Anyway, with the help of a view scoped bean, it could be something along these lines:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xe:jdbcQuery var="query" scope="request" connectionName="DB2"
        sqlQuery="SELECT COLUMN1 FROM MYTABLE" loaded="false" />
</xp:this.data>

<xp:dataTable id="dataTable1" binding="#{dataTable}"
    value="#{query}" var="row" indexVar="rowIndex">
    <xp:column id="column1">
        <xp:checkBox id="checkBox1"
            value="#{myBean.jdbcSelectedValues[rowIndex]}" uncheckedValue="false"
            checkedValue="true">
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertBoolean />
            </xp:this.converter>
        </xp:checkBox>
    </xp:column>
    <xp:column id="column2">
        <xp:text value="#{row}" />
    </xp:column>
</xp:dataTable>

<xp:button id="button1" value="print selected">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dataTable1"
        action="#{myBean.printSelectedColumnValues}">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

**the view scoped bean**

```
private List<String> jdbcValues;
private Map<Integer, Boolean> jdbcSelectedValues;

public Map<Integer, Boolean> getJdbcSelectedValues() {
    if (jdbcSelectedValues == null) {
        jdbcSelectedValues = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    }

    return jdbcSelectedValues;
}

public void printSelectedColumnValues() {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    XspDataTableEx dataTable = (XspDataTableEx) FacesUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance(), "dataTable");
    List<?> wrappedData = (List<?>) dataTable.getDataModel().getWrappedData();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean> entry : getJdbcSelectedValues().entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue()) {
            values.add((String) wrappedData.get(entry.getKey()).getColumnValue("COLUMN1"));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(values);

    jdbcSelectedValues.clear();
}
```

The idea is the one of grabbing the handle of the dataTable by means of the `binding` property (not really an orthodox way, I personally don't use these mixed approaches that disregard MVC pattern) and access the wrapped data that it contains: the wrapped data in nothing but the row set.

**WARNING** the only thing I am not sure of is what exactly `dataTable.getDataModel().getWrappedData()`. You might wanna try to print the class name before doing any cast and subsequent work. But the sense is that with the index number and the wrapped data you should be able to get to the rows.

Comment: xp:dataTable doesn't let you show rows with checkboxes.. you need to put checkbox control and put selected one in scopeVariable onclick event.. I thought there is an easy way to verify what checkboxe is selected in viewPanel. Otherwise it's not useful

Comment: Sure, It gets the job done just for a functionality that it takes just the code I posted above to replicate plus lots of things that don't apply to the context. Frankly I don't see how much more useful it can be. Anyway what I wrote, you can still apply it to the view - the binding and model data thing - so the answer is right there in front of you if you're still interested

Comment: Thank you shillem